# Covariance Matrix Update

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, means, variance

I am building a Multivariate (in my case 3-dimensional) Gaussian Distribution from a set of 3-dimensional data. I want to update my model with new incoming data. Updating the means of all the 3 dimensions is straightforward. Updating the covariance matrix, however, is not. My question is, is there a mathematical set of equations for updating the covariance matrix.